# Deserializing Xml string into object with List<>

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a xml string to a custom class, but I can get my "Riesgo" field filled with asegurado class:

```
<xml xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
    <CodPostal>28029</CodPostal>
    <Canal>216 </Canal>
    <FormaPago>M</FormaPago>
    <ConSeguro>N</ConSeguro>
    <FechaEfecto>01/01/2014</FechaEfecto>
    <Riesgo>
        <asegurado>
            <sexo>H</sexo>
            <edad>37</edad>
            <parentesco>M</parentesco>
        </asegurado>
        <asegurado>
            <sexo>M</sexo>
            <edad>34</edad>
            <parentesco>C</parentesco>
        </asegurado>
        <asegurado>
            <sexo>H</sexo>
            <edad>4</edad>
            <parentesco>D</parentesco>
        </asegurado>
    </Riesgo>
</xml>
```

I have tried several things but the List inside Riesgo always come null.

```
 public class TarificadorObject
    {

        [DataContract]
        [Serializable]
        [XmlRoot("xml")]
        public class TarificadorIn
        {
            [XmlElement("CodPostal")]
            public Int32 CodPostal { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Canal")]
            public Int32 Canal { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Riesgo")]
            [XmlArrayItem("asegurado", Type = typeof (Asegurado))]
            public List<Asegurado> asegurado
            {
                get { return _asegurados;  }
                set { _asegurados = value; }
            }

            [XmlElement("FechaEfecto")]
            public string FechaEfecto { get; set; }

            private List<Asegurado> _asegurados = new List<Asegurado>();
        }



        [Serializable]
        public class Asegurado
        {
            [XmlAttribute("sexo")]
            public string sexo { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("edad")]
            public Int32 edad { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("parentesco")]
            public string parentesco { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to programmatically create an instance of the class, serialize it and compare to the file you want to deserialize; I guess some small configuration error of the type is the cause of the problem.

Comment: how about :http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-linq.html

Comment: btw; you don't need `[Serializable]` or `[DataContract]` here.

Comment: Marc. The serializable and Datacontract are used for wcf service and asp.net. Thanks for your answer gonna check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
[XmlArray("Riesgo")]
[XmlArrayItem("asegurado", Type = typeof (Asegurado))]
```

not `XmlElementAttribute` (which causes the list contents to be placed *directly* under the parent).

Actually, you can be more frugal if you want; the `Type` is implied (from the list) and can be omitted if you want.

Note also that these are wrong:

```
[XmlAttribute("sexo")]
public string sexo { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute("edad")]
public Int32 edad { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute("parentesco")]
public string parentesco { get; set; }
```

They are not xml attributes - they are elements; you can replace that with:

```
public string sexo { get; set; }
public int edad { get; set; }
public string parentesco { get; set; }
```

(the default behavior is an element named for the property)